# JavaScript Open new tab with custom url ON CLICK anywhere in the body but once till refresh

Tags: javascript

I made a JS code to open a new tab with custom URL whenever the user clicks anywhere on the site/body.

The code goes as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
    window.open(
  'https://google.com/',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
 }
</script>

<body onclick="load()">
```

this code works fine but I want this on click function to happen only once till the main website refreshes. And when the new tab opens, it should not be active instead the main website should be active.

However I tried `<body onclick=" load(); this.onclick=null;">` it didn't work.. since, it directly states that it is null.

I hope I m clear, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two questions:

1. Click event only trigger once till the main website refreshes
2. New tab shouldn't get active.

For the first quetsion:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
    document.body.removeEventListener('click', load)
    window.open('https://google.com/', '_blank')
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', load)
  }
</script>
```

For the second question: **It's impossible,** but you can open the main website's page instead of google:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
    // open next page and it will get active
    window.open('https://my.domain.com/next_page', '_blank')
    // Redirect the current tab to google
    location.href = 'https://google.com'
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', load)
  }
</script>
```

**Updates:**

Combine:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('redirected', '1')
    // open next page and it will get active
    window.open('https://my.domain.com/next_page', '_blank')
    // Redirect the current tab to google
    location.href = 'https://google.com'
  }

  if (!sessionStorage.getItem('redirected')) {
    window.onload = function() {
      document.body.addEventListener('click', load)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The first one works great. thanks. but you sure regarding the second one, i mean, there is a site `https://otorrents.com/` which does the same where this instead of using new tab it opens a new window by keeping the main site active.... that would be awesome to learn too. can you check that one and let me know how it works.

Comment: I use Chrome but it seems doesn't keeping the main site active.

Comment: @Milk Lee, the second snippet code works great, but once i open the main site in new tab it again refreshing the event listener and the onclick function load again.. can't we limit that to once with the second code..?

Comment: @harishk Updated.

Comment: the update works great, but instead of once, it does it for twice and later it doesn't .. can we just limit to once.